# Get only noun words on google translation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, translation

There is a problem on **Cloud Translation** of GCP when I send a request with the word of "ор" [ In Mongolian it means "bed" in noun word ]. Unfortunately I'm getting verb of this translation. Is there any solution for this ? Example below

**Request :**

```
{
  "q": "ор", // In Mongolian it means "bed"
  "target": "en",
  "format": "text",
  "source": "mn",
  "model": "nmt"
}
```

**Response :**

```
{
  "data": {
    "translations": [
      {
        "translatedText": "Go to bed", //I should've got "bed" but i got this in verb
        "model": "nmt"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it is impossible. There is nothing in the API docs I could find previously but I assume nothing was added recently.

Comment: You could run `stanza` (by Stanford University researchers in Python) to perform NLP and extract from the English text, by tokenizing it and getting the noun value, could be a solution.